# Linq to objects giving strange error

Tags: runtime-error, linq-to-objects

I have the following code:

```
List<JobPortalInfo> jobPortalInfos = uow.JobPortalInfoRepository.GetQuery()                         
    .Where(x => x.Job.Id == emailHash.JobId)
    .ToList();

var temp = uow.EmailRepository.GetQuery()
    .Where(x => jobPortalInfos.Any(y => (y.Contact != null && y.Contact.Id == x.ContactId)))
    .ToList();
```

When I run the 2nd statement, I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'CR.Data.JobPortalInfo'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

JobPortalInfo has a 1-[0 or 1] with Customer and Customer has a 1-* with Email.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you see LINQ2Objects?

Comment: A quick glance, it may be your use of Any. Any does not return an object. It returns a bool.

Comment: @NickZimmerman Which is exactly what `Where` method expects.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The Where method wants a boolean comparison. In the above example, there is no comparison in the Where just an Any returning a bool so effectively, it was saying Where true || false. Which is probably not what he was expecting. Trying to lead to a solution. And it appears he got there, with or without my help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

jobPortalInfos is Linq to Objects, but EmailRepository is still an IQueryable/Linq To Entites.  It doesn't know how to convert the LinqToObject jobPortalInfos to a Sql Server object.

I ended up doing this:

```
List<JobPortalInfo> jobPortalInfos = uow.JobPortalInfoRepository.GetQuery()                         
    .Where(x => x.Job.Id == emailHash.JobId)
    .ToList();

List<long> contactIds = jobPortalInfos
    .Where(x => x.Contact != null)
    .Select(y => y.Contact.Id)
    .ToList();

var temp = uow.EmailRepository.GetQuery()
    .Where(x => contactIds.Contains(x.ContactId))
    .ToList();
```

Not sure if there is a more concise way to do this or not, but it seems to work.